# Target a specific div on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
    <div class="post-story">

                <div class="post-story-text">
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                      $(".more").click(function(){
                        var overvalue = $(".post-story-text").css("overflow-y");
                            if (overvalue=="hidden") {
                          $(".post-story-text").addClass("more-ex");
                          $(".post-story").addClass("more-story-ex");
                          }
                          else {
                          $(".post-story-text").removeClass("more-ex");
                          $(".post-story").removeClass("more-story-ex");
                          }
                        }); 
                    });
                </script>
                As HTC readied a new version of its flagship smartphone, it planned for many challenges. It didn't know that one of them would be Roshan Jamkatel, a teenager from Schaumburg, Ill.





This is true, but Tesla is more of a niche seller than a mass-market player. Which might be what HTC becomes if sales of its all-new phone don't set some all-new records.
    <div class="more">....Continue Reading</div>
                </div>
```

I'm working on project to show different posts, as the post is very long I included a button to continue reading but the problem is when I click on "...continue reading" or (`.more`) all the divs expand but I want only that particular div to expand.

Comment: Post Your sample HTML

Comment: <div class="post-story">
    
    <div class="post-story-text">
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".more").click(function(){
        var overvalue = $(".post-story-text").css("overflow-y");
       if (overvalue=="hidden") {
        $(".post-story-text").addClass("more-ex");
        $(".post-story").addClass("more-story-ex");
        }
        else {
        $(".post-story-text").removeClass("more-ex");
        $(".post-story").removeClass("more-story-ex");
        }
      }); 
     });
    </script>
"..Post"
 <div class="more">....Continue Reading</div>
    </div>

Comment: @Pankaj - not in the comments... update the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".more").click(function () {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.post-story');
        var overvalue = parent.find(".post-story-text").css("overflow-y");
        if(overvalue == "hidden") {
            parent.find(".post-story-text").addClass("more-ex");
            parent.find(".post-story").addClass("more-story-ex");
        } else {
            parent.find(".post-story-text").removeClass("more-ex");
            parent.find(".post-story").removeClass("more-story-ex");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Words: EVENT DELEGATION

[Click here for Explaination](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)